# Should I use `key` for other widget type, such as `FutureBuilder` and `StreamBuilder`?

Tags: flutter

It is recommended to use `key` in a collection of `StatefulWidget`, does that imply we should use `key` for `FutureBuilder` and `StreamBuilder` as well (because apparently, these are not `StatelessWidget`.

Update: the recommendation comes from [When to Use Keys - Flutter Widgets 101 Ep. 4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you are getting the idea that you should use a key in a collection of StatefulWidget; that is true in specific cases but generally you don't need to worry about them.

Some of the specific cases where it becomes important to use keys are enumerated in the [StatefulWidget docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html#performance-considerations), but that probably wouldn't apply to a list but rather to the individual items in the list and is more applicable when you start moving things around a lot. If you're experiencing performance issues you'd probably get more benefit from making the individual elements of your list into a StatefulWidget subclass rather than building them within the list generator function, than you'd get from messing with keys.

But realistically, in most cases you're probably better off not using keys until you start experiencing performance problems or you're moving things around in your page, and then possibly start considering them.

EDIT: now I've watched the [video posted in the comment from the OP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc), I get a better idea of what he's talking about. Once again though - the video talks about when to use keys in specific scenarios i.e. ordering a list that changes order, keeping a scroll position, etc.

In general, [**most of the time you don't [need keys]**](https://youtu.be/kn0EOS-ZiIc?t=40). If you're building a list that is moved around and the root of each list item is a FutureBuilder, then yes you'd need to give it a key, but unless your usage falls into one of the examples given in the video you probably don't need to use a key.

If you have a question about a particular scenario where you are using a FutureBuilder or StreamBuilder and you think a key might be necessary but you're not sure, open a question asking about that. This is a pretty broad question - I'm sure you could come up with a contrived example of when a FutureBuilder or StreamBuilder needs a key but in general no.

Comment: "where you getting the idea [...] use key in a collection": here from the "widget 101" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc

Comment: I've added a bit more after watching that video. I stand by my original opinion although I've made a few slight edits; most of the time you don't need to use keys except the few specific cases in the video